# jquery each loop get margin of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 7 elements with different margin-left and margin-top properties set on them through css styles on css file. I want to loop through them and collect these margins.

My jquery looks something like this now:

```
var $elements = $(".elements");
var elementsMargins = [];
$elements.each(function(index){
    var elementObj = {
        elIndex: index,
        elMarginLeft: this.css("margin-left"),
        elMarginTop: this.css("margin-top")
    };

    elementsMargins.push(elementObj);
});
```

However, I am not able to collect these values. Can someone advice or suggest anything to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `css()` is a jQuery method you have to wrap `this` in `jQuery` to use the method. Please use:

```
$(this).css("margin-left"),  //and
$(this).css("margin-top")
```

instead of `this.....`

**And**, I would suggest using the `map()` method. You do not need to explicitly specify the `index` as it will be matching the index in the array of each object.

```
var elementsMargin = $('.elements').map(function() {
    return {
        elMarginLeft: $(this).css('margin-left');
        elMarginTop: $(this).css('margin-top');
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: Nice, you saved my day, quite stupid error from my side I would say. And thanks for the advice on map()